# How to decode audio stream using tornado websocket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, tornado, torchaudio

I get an ogg-encoded audio stream received chunk by chunk via `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`. My task is to decode it on-the-fly into PCM samples to feed into another algorithm. So the ideal decoding API for me would be something like:

```py
class Decoder():
    def push_encoded(self, chunk: bytes):
        # TODO: Implement this.

    def pop_decoded(self) -> PCMSamples:
        # TODO: Implement this.
```

In other words I need a decoder that internally holds two buffers: the first is to accumulate non yet decoded bytes, the second for already decoded samples.

Alternatively it might be a callback-driven API like:

```py
class Decoder(callback: Callable[[PCMSamples], None]):
    def push_encoded(self, chunk: bytes):
        # TODO: Implement this.
```

I tried to use `torchaudio.io.StreamReader` to implement the API above since I already use this package, but as it turns out it's not that obvious to achieve.

Is there an easy way to implement one of the APIs above using `torchaudio` or there're other packages more suitable for the task?